# Ошибка при записи в файл, записываются все строки вместо необходимых

Tags: python

```
inp = open("input.txt", 'r')
out = open("output.txt", 'w')
chas= {
    1: out.write('9 45'), 
    2: out.write('10 35'), 
    3: out.write('11 35'), 
    4: out.write('12 25'), 
    5: out.write('13 25'),
    6: out.write('14 15'),
    7: out.write('15 15'),
    8: out.write('16 05'),
    9: out.write('17 05'),
    10:out.write('17 55') 
 }
chas=int(inp.read())
out.close()
inp.close()
```

При выводе в исходящем фале выводятся все значения. Как исправить, чтобы при вводе от 1 до 10 в файл записывалось только одно соответствующее значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы вызываете `out.write(...)` многократно со всеми наборами данных. В словарь попадают значения, возвращаемые этим методом . В итоге произошла запись в файл определенное кол-во раз, а словарь инициализировался возвращенными значениями.

Чтобы исправить, нужно убрать вызов метода `out.write(...)` в словаре. Заменить его данными, которые Вы хотите записать и вызывать один раз, передавая данные с нужным ключом:

```
chas= {
    1: '9 45', 
    2: '10 35', 
    3: '11 35', 

    # и т.д.
 }

key = int(inp.read())
out.write(chas[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том, что ключи и значения словаря будут вычисляться, поэтому вызов метода выполнялся.
Это заметно при прогоне этого примера:

```
chas = {
    1: print('9 45'),
    2: print('10 35'),
    3: print('11 35'),
    4: print('12 25'),
    # ...
}
# 9 45
# 10 35
# 11 35
# 12 25
```

Как видно, код в значении выполнился. А чтобы этого не было, нужно в значении оставить ссылку на метод или лямбду.

Можно так, но проще хранить в словаре значения как было предложено в соседнем ответе:

```
inp = open("input.txt", 'r')
out = open("output.txt", 'w')
chas = {
    1: lambda: out.write('9 45'), 
    2: lambda: out.write('10 35'), 
    3: lambda: out.write('11 35'), 
    ...
 }
func = chas[int(inp.read())]
func()
out.close()
inp.close()
```

Comment: @user336063, если вам какой-нибудь понравился, то отметьте его: [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)